# onSharedPreferenceChanged() called several times

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Like I said in the title, the method `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` is called multiples times, and it's a problem in my case. In this method, I encrypt a password, and the "encrypting" is called multiples times too, so my application crash, and I have a sharedPreferences file of 2Mo.

Here is my code :

```
public class ParametreActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.parametres);

        PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                        .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    String mdp;
    if(key.equals("mdp")) {
            mdp = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
            if(mdp != null) {
                try {
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, SimpleCrypto.encrypt(mdp)).apply();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out that it is the `.commit` on the Editor object that is recurcive on this method, how can I avoid that?

Comment: Where is the Editor object? Further i see no `.commit();`.

Comment: I updated (it was in the Do stuf...)

Comment: You are not supposed to edit shared preferences in `onSharedPreferenceChanged`.

Comment: Why ? How can I do to encrypt a pass word else ?

Comment: Make a dialog to input the pass. Then encrypt. Then save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I found a solution (not verry pretty but it work :p )

I just use a boolean, to don't call a second time a commit